# Check abecedarian in recursive way (Not a homework, part of my learning)

Tags: java, recursion

I have created this function to check abecedarian with while loop (A word is said to be "abecedarian" if the letters in the word appear in alphabetical order, such as "abdest")-

```
public static boolean isAbecedarian(String s) {
                int index = 0;
                char c = 'a'; 
                while (index < s.length()) {
                        if (c > s.charAt(index)) {
                                return false;
                        }
                        c = s.charAt(index); 
                        index = index + 1;

                }
                return true;
        }
```

I want to change this function to a recursive function and I have written this function -

```
public static boolean isAbecedarianrec(String s){
                char first = s.charAt(0);
                char second = first ++;
                if (first<second){
                         return isAbecedarianrec(s);
                }

                return false;
}
```

recursive function is not working as it should and I am not getting the expected result. Please check and help me to pin point the issue with this function.

Note - As I mentioned this is not a homework question and it is part of my self Java learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically with recursion you need two things:

1. A base case (e.g. empty string, zero, etc.)
2. A way to check part of the more complex case, and then reduce it to a simpler recursive call.

The empty string does form a good base case here - it's trivially abecedarian.  So the first part of your recursive method should be to check for the empty string and return `true`.  This forms the base case that will be the termination of your recursive method in the "happy path" case.

Otherwise, you know you have a non-empty string.  The recursive decomposition can be achieved by checking its first character, then recursively calling with the rest of the string.  However, in order to perform the check, you'll need to remember what the previous character of the string was (just like `c` in the iterative method), so you'll need an additional argument to the recursive call to act as a sort of variable.

This is not uncommon with recursion - often the majority of the work is done in a "helper" method, and the public method just calls this with initial/dummy values.

Putting these together then, a solution would look something like the following:

```
// s must not be null
public boolean isAbecedarianrec(String s) {
    return isAbecedarianRecImpl(s, (char)0);
}

private boolean isAbecedarianRecImpl(String s, char c) {
    if (s.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else {
        if (c > s.charAt(0))
            return false;
        else
            return isAbecedarianRecImpl(s.substring(1), s.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. The following code `char second = first++` should be `char second = s.charAt(1);`
2. The recursive call should be `return isAbecedarianrec(s.substring(1));`

Finally, you need length checks where appropriate. On method entry, ensure the string has at least 2 characters if not, return true.

When using recursion, you need to keep two things in mind. First, the input to the recursive should in some way be different than the previous input. Second, there must be a valid stopping point so that you don't recurse infinitely and thereby run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks John..I was confused about the input to recursive call...It is clear now

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have pointer arithmetics (it seems you are trying to do something like that). You code will take the first char (always the first char of the String), and afterwards it will increment the char (turning 'a' into 'b' etc) and furthermore store the value to second also. This means that first and second will always contain the same value.

A simple (but not very efficient solution could be:

```
public static boolean isAbecedarianrec(String s, char c){
            if (s.equals("")) return true;
            char first = s.charAt(0);
            if (first>=c){
                     return isAbecedarianrec(s.subString(1), first);
            }

            return false;
}
```

(Notice that I have also flipped the equality. That seemed to be wrong).

Call the function with the value of the lowest character. E.g.: `isAbecedarianrec(s, 'a')`.

Notice that this solution (like yours) requires that the code points of the letters have the same numerical order as the alphabetical order of the letters. That is not generally correct, for example you will see strange results if the string contains both capital and small letters.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I am learning 2 languages simultaneously..3-3 days a week, sometime they get mixed and create the problem like this..but my intention is to learn...and your answer helped..

Answer (score 0):

To create a recursive function, you need two things: an end case that stops execution, and some way to modify the successive calls to the recursive function.

In your case, you have one end case covered (the case where the string is not abecedarian), but not the other. For your function to ever return true, it needs to contain a `return true` statement or a `return` statement with a boolean comparison in it. The condition in this case would probably be finding the end of the string (being called with an empty string).

You are also missing a modification of successive calls: every call to `isAbecedarian` is made with the same string. Depending on what works best in Java, you could either shorten the string by 1 character on every call, or pass the index as an argument to the function and increment it on each call.